# Ideal DB framework for RESTful web service

Tags: database, rest, jakarta-ee, frameworks, connection

I have a minimal web service (password manager) that I'm developing.
Currently, I handle DB connections without using any DB framework, (I want to keep my web service minimal). I open a live connection per method and closes it in the same method. That's it.

Is this ideal? Or is there a lightweight DB framework out there? One that's preferably small but efficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Sprint JDBC Templates before: they are lightweight, allow you to tightly define your own SQL, and take care of all the connection stuff for you.

More info here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html

I'd start with the `SimpleJdbcTemplate` described on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend reading about CouchDB. It can be embedded, it's small, using json and rest natively, and you can create simple web apps on top of it without anything else.